# Mounting entire volumes as secrets in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am running locally a container as follows:

```
docker run --rm \
  --name=my-container \
  --net=host \
  -v $(pwd)/producer.properties:/etc/replicator/producer.properties \
  -v $(pwd)/consumer.properties:/etc/replicator/consumer.properties \
  -v $(pwd)/service-keystore.jks:/etc/replicator/destination.keystore.jks \
  -v $(pwd)/service-truststore.jks:/etc/replicator/destination.truststore.jks \
  repo/image
```

The problem is that all files mounted as volumes contain sensitive data.

I am trying to port the above to `kubernetes`

How can I mount the files, and treat them as secrets at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) resource from the [files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#generating-a-secret-from-files) with name `secretname`(example) and mount the secret into the container directly as below

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: secretname
  containers:
  - name: containername
    image: imagename
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secret-volume
      readOnly: true
      mountPath: "/etc/secret-volume"
```

Comment: I assume the secret should be created from my files containing sensitive data, right?

Comment: yes  refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#generating-a-secret-from-files